# Set client source port to listening port with C sockets

Tags: c, sockets, networking

Currently, I'm following [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/net2/bgnet.html) to create a stream server and client, both in the same application. Basically, it's a server that also makes connection requests (client). I'm using the codes from client.c and server.c from these [examples](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/examples/).

What I'm looking to do is to set the client source port to be same as the server listening port if that is even possible. In other words, listen on port 8888, and make outbound connections with connect() using the same 8888 port. Currently, the default is that connections use different random ports each time.

1. Is is possible to listen and make connections using the same port and how could it be done.
2. I read that using random ports each time is the common practice but it can run out of ports or use a blocked port. How true is this?

How do I go around this if I would like to set a fixed port for all connections?

Comment: Regarding using blocked ports, no the system will not do that. And will you really have several *thousands* of outgoing connections from your program? That's the only case you need to worry about running out of ports.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to set the source port for a client socket by calling `bind` on the socket in question.   This is a problem however if you already have a server socket bound to that port.

The exact port number used for a TCP client socket is typically unimportant.  Unless you have a very specific requirement, it is better to let the OS choose an available port.